# How to use private go package with modules

Tags: git, go, github, registry, go-modules

I have a project which is providing an API but not under github.com, it’s under `github.ny.nts.com`
How can I use it on my code?

I’ve added to a new program and in the import I put:

```
import “github.ny.nts.com/fds/client”
```

Now when I run go mod init it didn't add anything (which is related to this project) to the go.mod file

How can I define the “registry” (similar to nodejs/npm when you can tell from where to download the packages) on go and tell gomod to take it my company git?

I'm able to clone the project without any problem so I don't have any access problem to the project git.

Comment: You can try with GOPRIVATE=github.ny.nts.com, and re-run go mod tidy

Comment: There is no package registry/repository in Go.

Comment: @Adrian, yes, we kinda do now: the sum database and module proxy.

Comment: Kind of but not really, because they're still simple proxies over arbitrary source repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can implicitly install the dependency by running `go get` in your project root like

`$> go get github.ny.nts.com/fds/client`

If the repository is private you'll need to implement a workaround, as `go get` defaults to `https` for cloning git repos. Running the following from your project folder will tell git to use SSH (and therefore your stored credentials) when pulling packages from your repo for this project:

`$> git config insteadOf."https://github.ny.nts.com/".use "git@github.ny.nts.com:"`

Once that's done, you should be able to run `go get ...` and pull your package